# XML and Variables

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on a project and have a problem.
I've recently established that one cannot change variable values and can't seem to find a work around for this problem. I need to create the code to be generic and I can't get this right.

My XSLT Code
.........

```
                   <tracklist>
                        <xsl:for-each select = "VinylRecord/Tracks/Song">

                            <xsl:choose>

                                <xsl:when test = "@Track = 1">
                                    <xsl:element name="side{@Side}">

                                    <xsl:variable name = "d" select = "@Track"/>

                                        <xsl:for-each select = "../Song">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test = "@Side = ../Song/following:: @Side">

                                                    <track>

                                                        <xsl:attribute name = "no">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select = "@Track" />
                                                        </xsl:attribute>

                                                        <xsl:attribute name = "runtime">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select = "Length" />
                                                        </xsl:attribute>

                                                        <xsl:value-of select = "text()" />

                                                    </track>

                                                </xsl:when>                                               
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:for-each>


                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:when>

                            </xsl:choose>

                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tracklist>
```

XML document
............

```
    <Tracks>
        <Song Side="A" Track="1">
            The Nerve
            <Length>2.58</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="A" Track="2">
            Backfire
            <Length>3.22</Length>
        </Song> 
        <Song Side="A" Track="3">
            Clipping
            <Length>4.05</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="A" Track="4">
            Spotlight
            <Length>3.21</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="A" Track="5">
            No Response
            <Length>4.01</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="A" Track="6">
            Pins and Needles
            <Length>4.05</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="B" Track="1">
            Goodbye
            <Length>4.09</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="B" Track="2">
            Odds
            <Length>3.01</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="B" Track="3">
            Electrify
            <Length>3.49</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="B" Track="4">
            Armistice
            <Length>3.54</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="B" Track="5">
            Lost Year
            <Length>3.13</Length>
        </Song>
        <Song Side="B" Track="6">
            Burden
            <Length>9.06</Length>
        </Song>
    </Tracks>
```

...

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Expected Result
...............

This is only a snippet of the overall program displayed above, but the result is suppose to show as:

```
        <tracklist>
            <sideA>
                <track no="1" runtime="2.58">The Nerve</track>
                <track no="2" runtime="3.22">Backfire</track>
                <track no="3" runtime="4.05">Clipping</track>
                <track no="4" runtime="3.21">Spotlight</track>
                <track no="5" runtime="4.01">No Response</track>
                <track no="6" runtime="4.05">Pins and Needles</track>
            </sideA>
            <sideB>
                <track no="1" runtime="4.09">Goodbye</track>
                <track no="2" runtime="3.01">Odds</track>
                <track no="3" runtime="3.49">Electrify</track>
                <track no="4" runtime="3.54">Armistice</track>
                <track no="5" runtime="3.13">Lost Year</track>
                <track no="6" runtime="9.06">Burden</track>
            </sideB>
        </tracklist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This XSLT solution is quite straight-forward**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="Song"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Song[not(@Side = current()/@Side)][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <tracklist>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tracklist>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Song"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Song[not(@Side = preceding-sibling::Song[1]/@Side)]">

  <xsl:element name="side{@Side}">
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select=
   "key('kFollowing', generate-id(preceding-sibling::Song[1]/@side))"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Song" mode="inGroup">
  <track no="{@Track}" runtime="{Length}"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></track>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Tracks>
    <Song Side="A" Track="1">
            The Nerve
        <Length>2.58</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="A" Track="2">
            Backfire
        <Length>3.22</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="A" Track="3">
            Clipping
        <Length>4.05</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="A" Track="4">
            Spotlight
        <Length>3.21</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="A" Track="5">
            No Response
        <Length>4.01</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="A" Track="6">
            Pins and Needles
        <Length>4.05</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="B" Track="1">
            Goodbye
        <Length>4.09</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="B" Track="2">
            Odds
        <Length>3.01</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="B" Track="3">
            Electrify
        <Length>3.49</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="B" Track="4">
            Armistice
        <Length>3.54</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="B" Track="5">
            Lost Year
        <Length>3.13</Length>
    </Song>
    <Song Side="B" Track="6">
            Burden
        <Length>9.06</Length>
    </Song>
</Tracks>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<tracklist>
   <sideA>
      <track no="1" runtime="2.58">
            The Nerve
        </track>
      <track no="2" runtime="3.22">
            Backfire
        </track>
      <track no="3" runtime="4.05">
            Clipping
        </track>
      <track no="4" runtime="3.21">
            Spotlight
        </track>
      <track no="5" runtime="4.01">
            No Response
        </track>
      <track no="6" runtime="4.05">
            Pins and Needles
        </track>
   </sideA>
   <sideB>
      <track no="1" runtime="2.58">
            The Nerve
        </track>
      <track no="2" runtime="3.22">
            Backfire
        </track>
      <track no="3" runtime="4.05">
            Clipping
        </track>
      <track no="4" runtime="3.21">
            Spotlight
        </track>
      <track no="5" runtime="4.01">
            No Response
        </track>
      <track no="6" runtime="4.05">
            Pins and Needles
        </track>
   </sideB>
</tracklist>
```

Comment: Thank you, just a question, this is only part of my overall document, why can't one use <xsl:key> inside of the default apply template = "/" ?

Comment: @Crossman: `xsl:key` is a global-scope (child of `xsl:stylesheet`) XSLT instruction. It is a *definition* of a key and is "static" -- can't be defined dynamically inside of a block of code such as `xsl:template`, `xsl:for-each`, ..., etc. One can use the `key()` function to reference a key anywhere in the XSLT code.

Comment: most of my code is in a single template, so creating all the the code with mine is a bit confusing. how would I initiate the first apply template ? I tried using <xsl:apply-templates> with the first template class but can't seem to get it right as it just repeats the same tracks in the sides following the first. Any Suggestions ? Or should I change all my code to work with templates

Comment: @Crossman: It is in the spirit of XSLT to use many small templates as this provides greater flexibility, reusability and maintainability. Having all code in a single, monolithic template usually means that the code is unnecessarily complicated and not optimal (often problematic and containing bugs). I strongly suggest that you pursue a true XSLT writing style.

Comment: I understand what you mean, just a bit complex for where I'm at with the language still. Just out of interest though, would it actually be possible to do it with for-each etc. without using the templates ?

Comment: @Crossman: Templates are more powerful and expressive (they support polymorphism) than just `xsl:for-each` and this means there are some tasks that can be done with templates, but not with `xsl:for-each`. THis said, this particular problem can be solved using `xsl:for-each` -- but I wouldn't recommend such solution.

Comment: Will try find a solution to the document using templates, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature": XSLT variables are designed not to be changeable. Actually they could be named constants. Working around that is difficult, it can be done using parameters. In most cases that isn't necessary if you use the XSLT programming attempt, where the programm is driven by the data through templates. Things like "for-each" are procedural ways that do not really fit in the XSLT idea. What do you want to get as a result?

After knowing the expected result, the sylesheet should look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Tracks">
 <tracklist>
  <sideA>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Song[@Side='A']"/>
  </sideA>
  <sideB>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Song[@Side='B']"/>
  </sideB>
 </tracklist>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Song">
 <track no="{@Track}" runtime="{Length}">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
 </track>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I was extremely sad about the variables and I can't seem to iterate the position in a coding manner either. I updated the original question and added the result. I just can't seem to be able to grasp the manner in which I need to go about to do this.

Comment: It needs to be performed generically though.

Comment: @Crossman: What do you mean by "generically"? Please, edit the question and *define* the problem: source XML document, wanted result, any rules that the transformation must implement. Then define the wanted genericity -- what can be generalized that in the original problem is specific.

Comment: @Andreas thats similar to what I had before but the tracklist can have any number of sides, so I have to create the sides as they come.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I edited the different headings. by generic code I mean that no matter how many sides (sideA, sideB...) the code must create it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a standard grouping problem.

If you're using XSLT 2.0, then

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Song" group-by="Side">
  <xsl:element name="Side{current-grouping-key)}">
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
      <track no="{position()}" runtime="{Length}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </track>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

With XSLT 1.0 it's rather more difficult, but still a textbook problem: look up "Muenchian Grouping" for the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do this in XSLT 1.0 ? Like I said its a project and I have to use XSLT 1.0